# Rename file in blueimp jquery fileupload before upload

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

i am searching now since hours for a solution in jquery fileupload to rename the file before upload.
in my index.php i have 5 variables with the information for the rename.

```
<?php
$wedate = $_GET['wedate'];
$wenumber = $_GET['wenumber'];
$artikelnumber = $_GET['artikelnumber'];
$liefnumber = $_GET['liefnumber'];
$liefbez = $_GET['liefbez'];
?>
```

and now i want to rename my file before upload to

$webdate_$wenumber_$artikelnumber_$liefnumber_$liefbez.filetype

Due to the situation that i am not very familiar with jquery and the upload handler i have not found a solution and hopefully someone can tell me how to do.

The whole index.php file looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin Demo
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */
-->
<?php
$wedate = $_GET['wedate'];
$wenumber = $_GET['wenumber'];
$artikelnumber = $_GET['artikelnumber'];
$liefnumber = $_GET['liefnumber'];
$liefbez = $_GET['liefbez'];
$filename=$wedate.'_'.$wenumber.'_'.$artikelnumber.'_'.$liefnumber.'_'.$liefbez.'.pdf';
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Force latest IE rendering engine or ChromeFrame if installed -->
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<![endif]-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Lieferbeilagen Upload Seite</title>
<meta name="description" content="File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&amp;drop support, progress bars, validation and preview images, audio and video for jQuery. Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads and client-side image resizing. Works with any server-side platform (PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, Node.js, Go etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Generic page styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!-- blueimp Gallery styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
<!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
<!-- CSS adjustments for browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-noscript.css"></noscript>
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css"></noscript>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <h1>Lieferbeilagen Upload Seite</h1>
    <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <form id="fileupload" action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
        <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <!-- The global file processing state -->
                <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress state -->
            <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Felddaten aus dem M3</h3>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="container"> 


    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="wedate" class="control-label col-xs-2">WE-Datum</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="wedate" value='<?php echo $wedate; ?>' readonly>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="wenumber" class="control-label col-xs-2">WE-Nummer</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="wenumber" value='<?php echo $wenumber; ?>' readonly>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="artikelnumber" class="control-label col-xs-2">Artikelnummer</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="artikelnumber" value='<?php echo $artikelnumber; ?>' readonly>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="liefnumber" class="control-label col-xs-2">Lieferantennummer</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="liefnumber" value='<?php echo $liefnumber; ?>' readonly>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="liefbez" class="control-label col-xs-2">Lieferantenbezeichnung</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="liefbez" value='<?php echo $liefbez; ?>' readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="liefbez" class="control-label col-xs-2">Dateiname</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filename" value='<?php echo $filename; ?>' readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>


        </div>
        <br>
    </div>  
</div>
<!-- The blueimp Gallery widget -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-filter=":even">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="size">Processing...</p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
            {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview">
                {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                {% } %}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">
                {% if (file.url) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
                {% } else { %}
                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                {% } %}
            </p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
            {% } else { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Templates/js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- blueimp Gallery script -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload audio preview plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload video preview plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-video.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload validation plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload user interface plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<!-- The main application script -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<!-- The XDomainRequest Transport is included for cross-domain file deletion for IE 8 and IE 9 -->
<!--[if (gte IE 8)&(lt IE 10)]>
<script src="js/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To change the filename before upload you need to do it on the client side browser, before the file even gets to your server side php. Please share your client-side javascript code to see what you're working with.

Comment: @RezaKarami, Hello Reza, Thanks for the information, i have added the whole code of my index.php file

Comment: Hello, can someone help on this issue?